# Bootstrap Link On-Hover-Effect Not Showing

Tags: html, css, hover, bootstrap-4, frontend

I was following [this tutorial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/badge/#links) to style links with Bootstrap, but when I add the `badge badge-info` classes to the `a` tag, it doesn't show the hover effect when I hover over it with the mouse, it just changes the background color. The code (It has some `Vue.js`):

```
<div class="mask">  
    <div class="mask-content">
        <h5>{{anime.title}}</h5>
        <!-- The link with the problem  -->
        <a class="badge badge-info text-white">Read More...</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Question: How to fix this problem and show the hover effect?**

Comment: Please, show us your code, so we could help you to find the problem

Comment: @Cenlan Added the code, it's actually mixed with some Vue.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to use the href attribute to use the natural hover effect from bootstrap. Here are a few ways to do this:

```
<a class="badge badge-info text-white" href="javascript:;">Read More...</a>

<!--FYI.. This will cause the page to jump to the top -->
<a class="badge badge-info text-white" href="#">Read More...</a>
```